# Main launcher =true not working in Xamarin android (system.typeloadexception)

Tags: java, c#, android, android-activity, xamarin.android

I made MapActivity.cs as main launcher as I was implementing map API on this activity, then after this I change "MainLauncher=true" in mainactivity of my app and removed it from Mapactivity, but when I debugged the application it kept opening at mapactivity.cs so I deleted it and debugged again then it threw this exception at the start.

```
System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type 'FinalProject_PU.MapActivity' from assembly 'FinalProject_PU, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.'
```

I have tried:

1. deleting bin and obj from the project and building the solution again.
2. changing the mainactivity.cs name to mapactivity.cs ( and it worked but I want the best practice approach to it, and why this is happening)

Comment: Are the mapactivity and mainactivity two different activities? If yes, have you do any change for its name? Try to close the project and VS to restart, and then debug again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if MainLauncher is hardcoded in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:noHistory="true" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/Theme.Splash" android:name=".SplashActivity">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/android-manifest#launchable-from-application-chooser